# embedded flash working in Chrome not in FireFox

Tags: html, flash

I am setting up a music blog that uses a embedded flash player on Blogger.

The flash player works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox any suggestions? Am I formatting my embed and object tags improperly?

http://mostlydirtyalwaysfresh.blogspot.com/

Comment: Found it. For some reason this in the object tag caused error: type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://mostlydirtyalwaysfresh.sharingizcaring.com/audio_player_black.swf" id="audioplayer"

Answer (score 1):

Removed: type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://mostlydirtyalwaysfresh.sharingizcaring.com/audio_player_black.swf" id="audioplayer"

From object tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using SWFObject to embed your swfs - it writes the object/embed tags for you, so you don't have to worry about all the different browser implementations:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: I'm having this issue whilst using swfobject-- because it makes the bad tag (that worked in previous versions of FF).